# Fair Game and Dice

Tags: probability, dice

Two players put a dollar in a pot. They decide to throw a pair of dice alternatively. The first one who throws a total of $ 5$ on both dice wins the pot. How much should the player who starts add to the pot to make this a fair game?

So my interpretation of this problem is that I first throw a dice and then the other person throws a dice afterwards. E.g. if I throw a 1, and if the other person throws a 4 wins the pot. So we are trying to find the expected payout?

Comment: Should just be 5.

Comment: Trevor, *you* should tell *us* how the rules of the game are. The answer to the question of course depends on that.

Comment: This is all you are given.

Comment: -1 for not defining the problem, even when asked

Comment: Are you sure your interpretation is right? The first paragrpah suggests (to me) that each player throws a pair of dice each time, and wins if they sum 5.

Comment: @leonbloy: It's not clear what's meant.  Feel free to submit an answer for whatever interpretation you get from it.  As @Ross says above, the problem hasn't been defined unambiguously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player 1 throws on odd throws and player 2 throws on even throws. This is a geometric distribution. So his distribution is $\left(\frac{8}{9} \right)^{2k} \cdot \frac{1}{9}$ and player 2's distribution is $\left(\frac{8}{9} \right)^{2k-1} \cdot \frac{1}{9}$. So player 1 must give $1/8$.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the probability $p$ that a $5$ is thrown and define $q = 1 - p$. The probability that the first player wins is $C=p+pq^2+pq^4+\ldots$; calculate this value. Now set $C=(1-C)(1+x)$ and solve for the extra contribution $x$.

Comment: So player $1$ throws on odd throws? On the first throw, the probability that he wins is $p$. On the third throw, the probability that he wins is $pq^2$ (e.g 2 failures and 1 success)? But he has only thrown the dice once right? So how can he have 2 failures?

Comment: For player 1 to win on turn 3, player 1 must have failed on turn 1, player 2 must have failed on turn 2, and player 1 must have won on turn 3.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your interpretation, let us define the rules as follows:  A and B alternately throw a single die.  If the sum of the last two throws is 5, the one who just threw wins.  Note that as stated, an initial 5 could win, or a series of throws of a different length than 2.  The analysis would change, but follow the same route.  The below requires precisely two throws to add to 5.

Let p be the probability that the first player wins.  Let q be the probability that the next player to throw wins given that he has received a chance of winning, that is that the last throw is less than 5.  Then if you receive a throw of 5 or 6 your chance of winning is p.  So q=1/6 (that you win on this throw) + (1-p)/3 (that you throw 5 or 6 and then win) +(1-q)/2 (that you throw <5, don't win this throw, but finally win.  p=(1-p)/3 (that you throw 5 or 6 and win)+2(1-q)/3 (that you throw <5 and win).

$q=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1-p}{3}+\frac{1-q}{2}$

$p=\frac{1-p}{3}+\frac{2(1-q)}{3}$

If I have the algebra right, p=15/32 and q=9/16, so the first player should withdraw $2/17.